# How to manually change the vector dimensions of a word in Gensim Word2Vec

Tags: python, vector, gensim, word2vec, vector-space

I have a Word2Vec model with a lot of word vectors. I can access a word vector as so.

```
word_vectors = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(wordspace_path)
print(word_vectors['boy'])
```

**Output**

```
[ -5.48055351e-01   1.08748421e-01  -3.50534245e-02  -9.02988110e-03...]
```

Now I have a proper vector representation that I want to replace the word_vectors['boy'] with.

```
word_vectors['boy'] = [ -7.48055351e-01   3.08748421e-01  -2.50534245e-02  -10.02988110e-03...]
```

But the following error is thrown

```
TypeError: 'Word2Vec' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there any fashion or workaround to do this? That is manipulate word vectors manually once the model is trained? Is it possible in other platforms except Gensim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since word2vec vectors are typically only created by the iterative training process, then accessed, the gensim `Word2Vec` object does not support direct assignment of new values by its word indexes.

However, as it is in Python, all its internal structures are fully viewable/tamperable by you, and as it is open-source, you can view exactly how it does all of its existing functionality, and use that as a model for how to do new things.

Specifically, the raw word-vectors are (in recent versions of gensim) stored in a property of the `Word2Vec` object called `wv`, and this `wv` property is an instance of `KeyedVectors`. If you examine its source code, you can see accesses of word-vectors by string key (eg `'boy'`), including those by `[]`-indexing implemented by the `__getitem__()` method, go through its method `word_vec()`. You can view the source of that method either in your local installation, or at Github:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/c2201664d5ae03af8d90fb5ff514ffa48a6f305a/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L265

There you'll see the word is actually converted to an integer-index (via `self.vocab[word].index`) then used to access an internal `syn0` or `syn0norm` array (depending on whether the user is accessing the raw or unit-normalized vector). If you look elsewhere where these are set up, or simply examine them in your own console/code (as if by `word_vectors.wv.syn0`), you'll see these are `numpy` arrays which *do* support direct assignment by index.

So, you *can* directly tamper with their values by integer index, as if by:

```
word_vectors.wv.syn0[word_vectors.wv.vocab['boy'].index] = [ -7.48055351e-01   3.08748421e-01  -2.50534245e-02  -10.02988110e-03...]
```

And then, future accesses of `word_vectors.wv['boy']` will return your updated values.

Notes:

• If you want `syn0norm` to be updated, to have the proper unit-normed vectors (as are used in `most_similar()` and other operations), it'd likely be best to modify `syn0` first, then discard and recalculate `syn0norm`, via:

```
word_vectors.wv.syn0norm = None
word_vectors.wv.init_sims()
```

• Adding new words would require more involved object-tampering, because it will require growing the `syn0` (replacing it with a larger array), and updating the `vocab` dict